# QuestPDF GeneratePdf Process.Start works locally but not when deployed

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Using QuestPDF to generate PDF documents. When debugging locally using VS it opens Adobe Acrobat or Chrome depending on Windows settings. After deploying the code to the hosting IIS server performing the same tasks, logs show all statements are executed successfully but nothing opens. No errors are thrown and server logs do not show any activity. Using the generate random filename method and tried several different paths with no success. The file does exist when using file manager either on the server or locally depending on which way the path is set. The only difference is deployed is using the release configuration and debugging locally is using the debug configuration. Neither configurations have any modifications.

Using .NET 7, Blazor Server Side, EF Core 7 and QuestPDF 2023.5.3. Here is the basics of the code being used, which is pretty much the same as the docs.

```
    var fileName = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName())}.pdf";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(SpecialDirectories.Temp, fileName);  // local machine
    // var fileName = $@"c:\temp\{fileName}";   // alternative attempt on server
    // var fileName = $@"\fileName";    // alternative attempt on server
    ...
    ...    build the pdf here from the data
    ...
    pdf.GeneratePdf(filePath);
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", filePath);
    // try different method for Process start
    // Process.Start("AcroRd32.exe", filePath);   // or
    // ProcessStartInfo psi = new()
    // {
    //    FileName = filePath,
    //    UseShellExecute = true
    // };
```

Basically running locally opens the PDF. This includes debugging using VS 2022 Ent, starting without debugging using release configuration and executing the EXE in the bin release folder. Thanks in advance.

Update: Instead of the Process.Start I have tried the JSRuntime.InvokeAsync("open", fileName, "_blank"); but am getting 500 <filename>.pdf not found. Not sure if this is the right path but may be getting me closer. If there is another way or a way to make either the Process.Start, the JavaScript call or some other way, I am open to giving it a try.

Comment: Your code didn't change the access rights of your app changed... When you run your code its your file access privileges. When IIS runs the code it's the permissions assigned to it which are by default very restrictive for good reasons.

Comment: @KJ I understand that, however not fully knowing how or what happens behind the QuestPDF GeneratePDF method. Such as where exactly the file is saved, local or on the server, I wanted to try different scenarios by chance one would work.

Comment: @BrianParker I understand the reason behind the restriction and am not trying to get around that, however my main attempt is to just get it to work as shown in the documentation. Just like most other 3rd party nuget package, I am assuming it should work from a deployed application not just in a local instance.

Comment: @KJ The PDF(PortableDocumentFormat) gets generated on the server and the users system including the GPU/CPU and all the other hardware process the data to render the data sent to it from the server. The issue I am having is the the PDF is rendered but am having an issue getting it rendered on the users computer. The options I have come up with are to either send the file in a file stream to the user's computer for rendering or execute an application like the browser to open the document and render it on the users system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it to work by doing the following.

Remove

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName());
... Code to generate the PDF remained unchanged ...
Process.Start("explorer.exe", filePath);
```

Added

```
var rootFileName = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName())}.pdf";
var fileName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "PDFReports", rootFileName);
var outputFileName = $"PDFReports/{rootFileName}";
... Code to generate the PDF remained unchanged ...
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", outputFileName, "_blank");
```

This generated the file in the wwwroot\PDFReports (fileName) folder and then opened the browser tab with the file from the same folder without the absolute path (outputFolder).

Comment: Hi, I could not get JSRunTime.InvokeVoidAsync to work. How do you inject the JSRuntime?

Comment: @alep.muqri Below are all the parts used to set JSRunTime. In the service Class.
public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; }
Using DI it into the constructor
public ReportService(IJSRuntime jSRuntime) {JSRuntime = jSRuntime; }
Then executed it as in the above post
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", outputFileName, "_blank");
'program.cs'
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(options =>
{ options.JSInteropDefaultCallTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1); })    .AddCircuitOptions(opt =>{ opt.DetailedErrors = true;});
Some options like timeout and others removed in the builder. Hope this helps.